# Yet another sh script to backup one directory

Tags: shell, posix, sh

A single directory should simply be backed up with the zip tool, and the time of the backup should be preserved in the file name. I have written a Posix shell script for this.

Can this script simply be converted into a `.bashrc` alias?

```bash
#!/bin/sh
if [ -z "$1" ]
  then
    echo "No argument supplied"
    exit
fi
fn=$(echo "backup_${1%/}_$(date +%F_%T).zip" | sed s/:/-/g)
echo "$fn"
zip -r "$fn" "$1"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This script is not super friendly.
(Also, absent some articulated motivation for turning it into a bash alias,
I would just leave it as a Bourne `sh` script.)

```
    echo "No argument supplied"
    exit
```

The word "argument" is *true*, but it's not very *helpful*.
Instead, prompt the user to enter "an input filename"
so it can be backed up.
We call this a *diagnostic* message,
one which offers a hint of "do this and you will win!"
rather than just announcing "you lose!".

Exiting with status `0` here seems Bad.
Prefer `exit 1`, so `make` and other callers
will know that things went horribly wrong.

A common idiom would be to first assign a meaningful parameter name:

```
in_file="$1"
```

and then work with the name rather than the arg position number.

## filename

```
fn=$(echo "backup_${1%/}_$(date +%F_%T).zip" | sed s/:/-/g)
```

The abbreviation is for "filename". Fine, we'll just accept that as-is.

The `%` percent is entirely too cryptic.
It strips trailing `/` slash,
but not e.g. trailing `/readme`, leaving that one intact.
You didn't offer any # comments, nor review context,
to motivate the "strip trailing slash" feature.
Recommend you just delete it.

I feel you probably want to use `$(basename "${in_file}")` here.
That would be a more salient concept.

As written, `fn` can include embedded `/` slashes,
and it seems that would be undesirable.
Using `basename` is an easy way to eliminate that possibility.

The `sed` is lovely.
Consider rephrasing it as `tr : -`

## quoting

I like the consistent use of quoting,
just in case filenames contain embedded SPACE characters.
Possibly you used `shellcheck` on this, which definitely is helpful.

Comment: Yes, I have used `shellcheck` for this. Thanks for your answer.